# kendo ui grid - newbie can't get basic sample to work

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm familiar with Telerik products but new to Kendo UI MVC wrappers.  I originally downloaded them a few months back and never got around to actually trying them so sadly my trial support has expired.

I've started a brand new Kendo UI MVC application in VS.NET.

I created my own Controller and View.

I copied over the batch editing example (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html) and swapped out a static list for the data the example was using.

The grid displays my data correctly.

However, updates send nothing to the server ({}) when clicking save.  Deletes also send nothing to the server ({}) when clicking save.  Creates send a record per new item, but the Name property is set to null.

Any ideas?

My code is below.

Thanks,
Kevin

*** My Model ***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class PersonalInterestModel
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

*** My Controller ***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models;


namespace KendoUIMvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ManagerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Manager/
        private static List<PersonalInterestModel> items = new List<PersonalInterestModel>();

        static ManagerController()
        {
            items.Add(new PersonalInterestModel() { ID = 1, Name = "Finance" });
            items.Add(new PersonalInterestModel() { ID = 2, Name = "Construction" });
            items.Add(new PersonalInterestModel() { ID = 3, Name = "Technology" });
            items.Add(new PersonalInterestModel() { ID = 4, Name = "Entertainment" });
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Editing_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(items.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Editing_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<PersonalInterestModel> products)
        {
            var results = new List<PersonalInterestModel>();

            if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    product.ID = items.Max(i => i.ID) + 1;
                    items.Add(product);
                    results.Add(product);
                }
            }

            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Editing_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<PersonalInterestModel> products)
        {
            if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    var target = items.Find(p => p.ID == product.ID);
                    if (target != null)
                    {
                        target.Name = product.Name;
                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Editing_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<PersonalInterestModel> products)
        {
            if (products.Any())
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    items.Remove(items.Find(p => p.ID == product.ID));
                }
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }

    }
}
```

*** My View ***

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Personal Interests";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models.PersonalInterestModel>()    
    .Name("Grid")    
    .Columns(columns => {        
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(140);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();        
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()         
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
        .Create("Editing_Create", "Manager")
        .Read("Editing_Read", "Manager")
        .Update("Editing_Update", "Manager")
        .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Manager")
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {    
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function() {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });        
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just try your code in my project it's work perfectly fine just do this,

MODEL

```
 public class PersonalInterestModel
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Tried that and it seemed to fix the creation (the name value is no longer passed as null, but it does not help updates and deletes.  The update and delete still send empty JSON objects to the server.

Comment: So when I originally tried that it seemed to not fully work.  But I must have been tired as this morning, without changing anything, it's working perfectly.  Thanks!  And damn those setters/getters!!

Comment: I am glad that it's working for you.Please mask as answer so its help full to other if they go with same problem.

Comment: @Jaimin one question tht I would like to ask you he mentioned in the above question products ...in create method i have just copy and paste the code and its not working for me it was saying product is not  in current context ...(if you got free time) would you pls clarify..

Comment: @pratapk: sorry i just don't understand you question.Product is not in current context.which product are you taking about.Please show some code in comment so i understand your problem.

Comment: ok I  am posting the question here would you pls look at this link if you have got time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008553/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-data-employeedetails-employeeid-is-null-or-no

Comment: @Jaimin    he mentioned ,he is using this method if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    product.ID = items.Max(i => i.ID) + 1;
                    items.Add(product);
                    results.Add(product);
                }
            }   in this method he is using products!= null where is the products term , he dint mentioned in model ....

Comment: @pratapk: He mentioned product in `Editing_Create` method like this

`([Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<PersonalInterestModel> products)`

Comment: @Jaimin sorry I have just seen that ....did u see that my post I have mentioned in that link......